# How to split a string into a map, grouping values by duplicate keys using streams?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, key-value

I want to convert the following

```java
String flString="view1:filedname11,view1:filedname12,view2:fieldname21";
```

to a `Map<String,Set<String>>` to get the key/value as below:

```
view1=[filedname11,filedname12]
view2=[fieldname21]
```

I want to use Java 8 streams. I tried

```java
Arrays.stream(tokens)
        .map(a -> a.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                a -> a[0], Collectors.toList()));
```

However the keys are also getting added to the value list.

Answer (score 9):

You should use a `Collectors::mapping` to map the array to an element.

```
String flString = "view1:filedname11,view1:filedname12,view2:fieldname21";

Map<String, List<String>> map = Pattern.compile(",")
    .splitAsStream(flString)
    .map(a -> a.split(":"))
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
            Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())
        )
    );

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
view1=[filedname11, filedname12]
view2=[fieldname21]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collectors#toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method as follows:

```java
String flString = "view1:filedname11,view1:filedname12,view2:fieldname21";

Map<String, Set<String>> map = Arrays
        .stream(flString.split(","))
        .map(str -> str.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                arr -> arr[0],
                arr -> new HashSet<>(Set.of(arr[1])),
                (s1, s2) -> {
                    s1.addAll(s2);
                    return s1;
                }));

System.out.println(map);
// {view1=[filedname11, filedname12], view2=[fieldname21]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off course @K.Nicholas solution with using downstream collector is perfect.

But I additionally created another alternative solution that also uses Stream API.
It is more complex and generates three streams, but it works too.

```java
String flString = "view1:filedname11,view1:filedname12,view2:fieldname21";

Map<String, Set<String>> map1 =
        Arrays.stream(flString.split(","))
                .map(a -> a.split(":"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        a -> a[0],
                        a -> a[1],
                        (a1, a2) -> a1 + "," + a2))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey(),
                        e -> Arrays.stream(e.getValue().split(","))
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet())));

map1.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using the following piece of codes:

```
String flString = "view1:filedname11,view1:filedname12,view2:fieldname21";
Map<String, List<String>> collect = Stream.of(flString)
        .flatMap(str -> Stream.of(str.split(",")))
        .map(keyValuePair -> keyValuePair.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it[0], Collectors.mapping(it -> it[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Simple output:

```
{view1=[filedname11, filedname12], view2=[fieldname21]}
```