# Merge two maps in Group by

Tags: java, java-stream

I have item List,

```
class Item {
    int id;
    String name;
    Map<String, String> map;
}

Item item1 = new Item(11, "name1", Map.of("k1", "v1"));
Item item2 = new Item(11, "name1", Map.of("k2", "v2"));
Item item3 = new Item(22, "name2", Map.of("k3", "v3"));
.
.
.

List<Item> list = List.of(item1, item2, item3 ...);
```

I wanted to group by id but map value retains different value as below,

```
List<Item> output = [ 11, "name1", map: { ["k1", "v1"],["k2", "v2"])) ], [ 22, "name2", map: { ["k3", "v3"] ] .....;
```

I tried with group by and returns, how can i retain map in it?

```
 Map<Integer, List<Item>> collect = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sole your issue you need to loop over the values, and create a new Item with grouping all maps in one:

```java
List<Item> response = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Item::getId, Collectors.toList()))
        .values().stream()
        .map(v -> {
            Item item = v.get(0);
            Map<String, String> map = v.stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> e.getMap().entrySet().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (a, b) -> a));
            return new Item(item.getId(), item.getName(), map);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect a structure of three nested maps from a list as follows:

```java
List<Item> list = List.of(
        new Item(11, "name1", Map.of("k1", "v1")),
        new Item(11, "name1", Map.of("k2", "v2")),
        new Item(22, "name2", Map.of("k3", "v3")));

Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> collect = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Item::getId,
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Item::getName,
                        e -> new HashMap<>(e.getMap()),
                        (e1, e2) -> {
                            e1.putAll(e2);
                            return e1;
                        })));

System.out.println(collect);
// {22={name2={k3=v3}}, 11={name1={k1=v1, k2=v2}}}
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to split a string into a map, grouping values by duplicate keys using streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66095515/14940971)</sup>